Getting the address of an array element and saving it
I am trying to get the address of a particular element in an array. I know I can get the root address, but how do I get the element address:
struct s_name
{
    char *name;
    int age;
};

I don't know the number of names until runtime, so
s_name *allNames;
maxNames = 10; // this is from somewhere else
allNames = malloc(sizeof(s_name) * maxNames);

So to get the second element, normally, allNames[1]
But I want to reverse this array in another array
s_name *revNames;
revNames = malloc(sizeof(s_name) * maxNames);

int revIndex = 0;

for ( int i = maxNames - 1; i >= 0; i-- , revIndex++ )
    revName[revIndex] = allNames[i];

So revName[0] should point to allNames[maxNames - 1] and I should be able to print revName[0].name
This fails.
I have tried
revName[revIndex] = &allNames[i];

I do not understand some fundamental thing here. With pointer arithmetic, allNames[1] should be the root memory address of allNames plus the size of s_name, to get at the actual address of the element, which I should be able to save and access.
There has to be some way to do this...

What is the definition of revNames? What is the type of revNames? This fails. What does it mean "it fails"? In what way? What fails and how? What do you observe and see? Do you see some error message? Please post verbatim full the output of your compiler.

@KamilCuk Crap. It is s_name *revNames;

First, be sure you are using C. Defining struct s_name { … } will not make a type named s_name in C. If sizeof(s_name) works in your program without a typedef for s_name, then you are using C++, not C.

Second, if you want revName[0] to “point to” allNames[maxNames - 1], then revName[0] must be a pointer. In that case, you cannot use revName[0].name, because . is for accessing a structure, not a pointer. You could use revName[0]->name. If you want to use revName[0].name, then revName[0] must be a structure, not a pointer, so it must have a copy of allNames[maxNames - 1], not its address. You need to decide which of these you want. If you want revNames[0] to be a pointer, then revNameshould be declare asstruct s_name **revName`.

Also, do not use revNames in some places and revName in others.

You seem to be working based on maxNames, so you're assuming the array will have maxNames elements. If this is not true, and the actual number of names entered is less than maxNames you may run into issues reversing by swapping [0] and [maxNames-1].

@EricPostpischil Yup, you are right. I slipped up writing a simple use case.

You seem to want for revNames to be a pointer to an array of pointers.
s_name **revNames = malloc(sizeof(*revNames) * maxNames);
for (int i = maxNames - 1; i >= 0; i--, revIndex++) {
    revName[revIndex] = &allNames[i];
}

Tip: sizeof(*revNames) is equal to sizeof(s_name*).

Great. This works. In real life, I am mapping 4 LED strings. I could reach each string by itself, but I want to be able to treat all the strings as a single string. This is on an arduino using the FastLED library. And some nice person marked the question down. Sigh.

arduino is in C++, not in C

@BigGuy There should exist no reason to use malloc in the first place then. Your Arduino can only handle up to n names - simply allocate enough room to support that worst-case scenario - no more, no less.

The example above is only a stripped down example of what I am doing. In actuality I have four strings of LED lights going around the room. The room is not square, so each string is a different length. I want to treat the four strings as a single unit so I can light a single LED "moving" it around the room. I add up the string lengths, then malloc some memory, then gather of each string using pointers to the LED element in each string. I can now use the string as a single entity. And the arduino easily has enough memory for about 500 LED lights, then about 500 pointers to the lights.
